# Substring method to identify char value in string value

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm having an issue with using the substring method to find a specific character in a string variable. Currently I have a for loop setup to loop over the length of a string variable named **name**. I then have my substring method inside of my if statement to find my specific character, in this case it is a ".".

I'm not able to get this to work and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
System.out.println("\nEnter name: ");
String name = in.nextLine();

int length = name.length();

for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
    
    if(name.substring(x,x+1).equals(".")) {
        
        System.out.println("Error! - name can not contain (.) values\n"
                         + "***************************************************");
        
            System.out.println("\nWould you like to capture another name?" +
            "\nEnter (1) to continue or any other key to exit");
            String opt1 = in.nextLine();

                // If statement to run application from the start 
                if (opt1.equals("1")) {
       
                     System.out.println("menu launch");
                }
                else { System.exit(0); }
    }            
    else { break; } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Instead of looping over the characters of the string, you could just use the [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method:

```
if (name.contains(".")) {
    // logic comes here...
```

Answer (score 0):

While Mureinik is correct on the best way to accomplish your goal, the reason your function does not work is because of your `else { break; }`  statement.

`break` terminates the loop so unless the very first character is a `.`, then the loop will exit immediately after the first iteration. When you want to increment the loop, the correct keyword is `continue` although it is unnecessary in this case because all of the logic is housed inside of the if statement. Since there is no other logic to avoid, you should delete the else statement.